# XXZ/Sine-Gordon equivalence, parameter correspondence; Luther point in XXZ?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, integrable-systems

It has been argued that isotropic XXZ model corresponds to 
an SG theory which flows to $K=1$, $u=0$ fixed point.

AFM XXZ model should correspond to some SG theory with K>1, u>0, which is dual to a massive Thirring model. We know if $K=2$, the massive Thirring model is free. It is called Luther point. Above that value, there are bound states.

My question is which parameter of XXZ corresponds to SG theory at Luther point?
Moreover, is there exact correspondence between parameters of XXZ and SG theory?

The convention is from Luttinger Liquid theory, $K=\frac{1}{\beta^2}$. $\beta$
is an usual convention of Sine-Gordon theory:

for example in *Lukyanov,Zamolodchikov: Exact expectation values of local ﬁelds in quantum sine-Gordon model*

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please consider spelling out acronyms when using them for the first time and/or adding explanatory links to make your question more accessible to those who might be able to answer your question but aren't familiar with your exact terminology. Also consider defining the variables (such as $K$) you use.

Comment: This might be of some use: https://www.psi.ch/cmt/TEACHINGBoard/SPRING10-lecture13.pdf

Comment: The problem is that the usual bosonization rule is given by free field correspondence, which is aprroximately good if the coupling is weak. However, bosonization is valid for all coupling. It seems to be difficult to find parameter correspondence. But we do know one fact: isotropic Heisenberg model and spin sector of SU(2) Hubbard model flows to K=1,u=0 fixed point.  This is clear if considering SU(2) symmetry. My question is that if there is any XXZ model flows to Luther-Emery point which is a massive free Dirac Fermion.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the related literature.

Haldane (1980 PRL) has calculated the Luttinger parameters of XXZ model in all parameter space.  Kmax=2 corresponds to limit of  half filling and  infinite unisotropy.

For spin sector of SU(2) Hubbard model, Kmax=2 is realized at the limit of non-filling and full-filling or infinite attractive interaction strength.